# Print multiple rows from select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have this table :

```
|      Pattern       | 
---------------------- 
|category    |varchar|
|patternexpr |varchar|
```

For example in this table I can have a category ISBN and its pattern to recognize it.

I want to create a procedure which takes three arguments : a table T, one of its column C and a category. I want to print every rows in column C in T table which respect the pattern associated.

This is what I did (**Updated with the correct answer**):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Recognize(T varchar,C varchar,catego varchar)
IS
    v_patt Pattern.CATEGOR%Type;

BEGIN
    SELECT patternexpr INTO v_patt
    FROM Pattern WHERE CATEGOR=catego;

    FOR myrow IN (SELECT C FROM T WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(C, v_patt) LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(myrow.C);
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

How can I declare a cursor to print my result without knowing the value of my variable patt in the "DECLARE" place ? Should I add another declare and begin...end bloc after the first query ? What is the best way to do it ?

(I'm working on Oracle SGBD)

Answer (score 1):

Use `REF CURSOR` to fetch records for this purpose.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Recognize(
    T      VARCHAR2,
    C      VARCHAR2,
    catego VARCHAR2)
IS
  v_patt Pattern.CATEGOR%Type;
  v_cur_txt VARCHAR2(400);
TYPE cur_type
IS
  REF
  CURSOR;
    v_cur cur_type;
    v_c VARCHAR2(20);
  BEGIN
    SELECT patternexpr INTO v_patt FROM Pattern WHERE CATEGOR=catego;
  v_cur_txt := 'SELECT '||C||' FROM '|| T ||'  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('||C||', '''||v_patt||''')';
  OPEN v_cur FOR v_cur_txt;
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur INTO v_c;
    EXIT
  WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_c);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_cur;
END;
/
```

**NOTE:** : Include proper `EXCEPTION` handling in your code for `NO_DATA_FOUND` etc.Also  as per Nicholas , make some validations by using `dbms_assert` package

Comment: @Gatsby It'd be a great idea to do some sort of validation(at least by using [dbms_assert](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/appdev.11203/e23448/d_assert.htm) package) of table and column names to prevent SQL injection when you use plain concatenation to construct a dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you don't need an explicit cursor:

```
for myrow in (select c from t where regexp_like(c, patt) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(myrow.c);
end loop;
```

I would call the pattern variable something like `v_patt`; that way, declared variables don't get confused with column names.

Comment: I have a problem by calling the procedure, my arguments are interpreted as caracters so it doesn't print anything... I'm calling it like this : execute Recognize('T','col','ISBN');

Comment: @Gatsby . . . Not at all.  Each database has its own scripting language.  As for the question in your column, I would suggest you ask another question.  It would seem that your original question here has been resolved.

Comment: @Gatsby How can it possibly work great? You are passing table name and column name in as a character to your procedure and use static SQL to query that table. Unless there is a table in your schema named `T` the procedure won't compile at all.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov . . . I'm not quite sure what you are referring to, but you might look at the question.  It refers to the table as `T`.

Comment: I'm referring to the `T` being passed in as a parameter of `varchar` data type.